# How best to roleplay an agent of the crown tasked with aiding the party

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, roleplaying

I am playing an inquisitive rogue joining a level 17 party. The party is already well established, having their own business ventures or terraforming land for their clan and whatnot. My idea for my character was to be a spy for the Crown, sort of like a deep state CIA agent. Since the party is getting so strong, I have been tasked with providing support to them and being a direct line of contact from the Crown to the party. I'm not to be involved in their personal businesses, but I am to otherwise assist them on their quest, which is currently to prevent Orcus and Iuz from being brought into the world, which is something the Crown obviously does not want.

My question is, how best should I roleplay a person who would understandably be slow to trust without seeming standoffish, and how do I do my "job" as an operative without seeming like I'm babysitting the party?

Comment: This is a bit too opinion based for this site I am afraid, unless you can define 'best' really well

Comment: @SeriousBri they did define best really well IMO. They said “who would understandably be slow to trust without seeming standoffish, and how do I do my "job" as an operative without seeming like I'm babysitting the party?” Which is IMO a pretty good definition of best.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica that is a very small aspect of RP, it gives a few limits, but doesn't tell us what 'best' means. Things like character stats, race, background and way more have a huge impact, as does what the individual player finds fun.